# Php mysql two table multiple data check

Tags: php, mysql

If i have two query data with PHP MySQL like this

```
<?php
    $a=msyql_query("select * from users");
    while($b=mysql_fetch_array($a,MYSQL_BOTH))
    {
        $c=$b['username'];
    }

    $d=msyql_query("select * from new_users");
    while($e=mysql_fetch_array($d,MYSQL_BOTH))
    {
        $f=$e['username'];
    }
?>
```

here is my question i have two table in a database

1- users

2 - new_users

if new_users field data['username'] exists in users table['username'] then update those fields that data retrieved from new_users table.How can i overcome?
I think there need to use array but give me some solution experts.
just i will attached a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yEqV.jpg) what i want to do?

Comment: What you have tried? SO is not code writing service.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
UPDATE user as u 
INNER JOIN new_user as nu ON  u.username = nu.username
SET information='data'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
$newuser=$mysqli->query("select * from newusers");
$result=$mysqli->query("select * from users");

while($res=$newuser->fetch_array())
{
   while($user=$result->fetch_array())
  {
     if($res['name'] ==$user['name']){
       $mysqli->query("update user set information=.'$res['information'].'");

     }

 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    $newuser=$mysqli->query("select * from newusers");
    while($new_user=$newuser->fetch_array())
    {
        $name=$new_user['name'];
        $result=$mysqli->query("select * from users where username='$name'");
        if(!empty($result)){
                 while($user=$result->fetch_array())
                {   
                       $mysqli->query("update user set information=.'".$new_user['information']."'");
                  }
        }

    }

?>
```